# What is the difference between the 2 functions that the latter doesn't consider all the strings in the argument but the first does

Tags: c, function, arguments, atoi

I wrote a function meant to act like the `<stdlib.h>` function `atoi`:

```c
int _atoi(char *s)
{
    int i, neg = 1, n = 0;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((s[i] >= '0') && (s[i] <= '9'))
            n = n * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
        else if (s[i] == '-')
            neg *= -1;
    }
    n *= neg;
    return (n);
}
```

When I run it with something like

```c
nb = _atoi("         +      +    -    -98 Battery Street; San Francisco, CA 94111 - USA             ");
printf("%d\n", nb);
```

The output is `-9894111`

But with a similar code like:

```c
int _atoi(char *s)
{
    int sign = 1, i = 0, res = 0;
    while (!(s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0') && s[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[i] == '-')
            sign *= -1;
        i++;
    }
    while (s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0' && s[i] != '\0')
    {
        res = (res * 10) + (s[i] - '0');
        i++;
    }
    res *= sign;
    return (res);
}
```

The output is `98`.
Which is what the real `atoi` function returns.

What's the difference between the two codes that would make the latter ignore everything after `8` (ie the `-` and the `94111`)?

Comment: Your first function always goes to the end the string. The while loop in your second function stops when it sees a non-number letter.

Comment: Neither function considers "all the strings".  The first looks at the entirety of the first string (all the values up to the first `'\0'`), while the second looks at the data up until the first non-digit.  A `char *` is not a string, but it often points to the first character of a string.

Comment: What was the input?

Answer (score 1):

The first function iterates on the whole string, combining all digits present into a single number even as they are separated by other characters. It also interprets any occurring `-` as a negative sign to apply to the resulting number.  This is definitely not the behavior of `atoi()`.

The second function first skips any non digits, only testing for `-` signs interpreted as changing the sign of the result. Then it iterates on the digits until it finds a non digit or the end of the string.  Thus is only interprets the first number present in the string, negating it possibly multiple times.  This produces a different value for your input string, but is still not the behavior of `atoi()`.

The Standard function `atoi` first skips any white space characters (as defined by `isspace()`, then accepts an optional sign (a single `+` or `-` character), then it parses any immediately following digits and stops at the first non digit.  For the test string, it returns `0`.

It is recommended to use `strtol()` over `atoi()` to avoid undefined behavior on strings that contain representations of integers beyond the range of type `int`.

Here is a simple implementation of `atoi()` with defined behavior:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int atoi(const char *s) {
    long n = strtol(s, NULL, 10);
    return n < INT_MIN ? INT_MIN :
           n > INT_MAX : INT_MAX : n;
}
```

If you want to implement your own function without `<stdlib.h>`, you can use:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int my_atoi(const char *s) {
    int res = 0;

    while (isspace((unsigned char)*s)) {
        s++;
    }
    if (*s == '-') {
        s++;
        // isdigit((unsigned char)*s) is guaranteed to be
        //   equivalent to `(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')`
        // isdigit(*s) would have undefined behavior if `char`
        //   is signed and `*s` is negative.
        // I am using the explicit test for clarity
        while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
            int digit = *s++ - '0';
            if (res < INT_MIN / 10
            ||  res == INT_MIN / 10 && -digit < INT_MIN % 10) {
                res = INT_MIN;
            } else {
                res = res * 10 - digit;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (*s == '+') {
            s++;
        }
        while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') {
            int digit = *s++ - '0';
            if (res > INT_MAX / 10
            ||  res == INT_MAX / 10 && digit > INT_MAX % 10) {
                res = INT_MAX;
            } else {
                res = res * 10 + digit;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @0___________: The behavior of `isspace()` depends on the currently selected locale. `isdigit()` conversely, is specified as matching exactly `'0'` to `'9'` so using it or an explicit test is equivalent. A smart compiler will combine both tests in `(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')` as a single comparison `((unsigned char)(*s - '0') < 10)` which does not access the `<ctype.h>` internal structures like `isdigit(*s)` might.  Incidentally, this algorithm works because the digits `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be consecutive in this order in the character set, unlike the letters `'a'` through `'z'`.

Comment: @0___________: I amended the answer with an explanation. Thank you for pointing this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

The loop condition of first code is `s[i] != '\0'`. This means the loop will run until the end of string, regardless of wheather unconverted character exists before that.

On the other hand, the loop condition of the last loop in the second code is `s[i] <= '9' && s[i] >= '0' && s[i] != '\0'`. This will make the loop stop at the first character that is not a digit.

Therefore, the first code will see `94111 -` after non-digit characters following `98` while the second code won't.